# how can i make a store the beginning and end of a Memory for best fit?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am given a max total size of unsigned int = 100000000 and we have to enter size of each processor but we do not know the amount of array there is going to be... Most people that i saw online already has already defined array size, so i was wonder if there are any other way to do the best fit algorithm without the array size. I can't seem to get a good way to create this algorithm. I have also tried doubly linked list and i'm having trouble

```
int MaxMem = 20000000;

struct PCB
{
    int ProcessID;
    unsigned int ProcessorSize;
    unsigned int Begin;
    unsigned int End;
    int sumOfMemory = 0;
    PCB ()
    {
        ProcessID = NULL;
        ProcessorSize = NULL;
        priority = NULL;
    }

    bool operator < (const PCB &c)
    {
        return priority < c.priority;
    }
    bool operator > (const PCB &c)
    {
        return priority > c.priority;
    }

    void rem(PCB &a)
    {
        a.ProcessID = NULL;
        a.ProcessorSize = NULL;
        a.priority = NULL;
        sumOfMemory -= a.ProcessorSize;
    }
};
 static int start = NULL;
 static int temp;

void best_fit(PCB a,vector<int> &memory)
{
    int bestfit = -1;
    unsigned int endMem = MaxMem;
    unsigned int tempMem = MaxMem;
       if((start == NULL) && (bestfit = -1))
        {
            temp = start;
            memory.push_back(a.ProcessorSize);
            bestfit = a.ProcessID;
            start = a.ProcessorSize;
            tempMem -= a.ProcessorSize;
            cout << "pushed" << endl;
        }
        else if((start != NULL)&& (bestfit = -1) && (a.ProcessorSize < memorySize) && (a.sumOfMemory < tempMem) )
        {
            memory.push_back(a.ProcessorSize);
            bestfit = a.ProcessID;
            tempMem -= a.ProcessorSize;
            temp = start;
            start += a.ProcessorSize;
            cout << "pushed!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
             cout << "No space" << endl;
        }

}
int main()
{
    PCB pcb;
    while(true)
    {
        vector<int> mem;
        cout << "process ID?" << endl;
        cin >> pcb.ProcessID;
        cout << "enter processor size?" << endl;
        cin >> pcb.ProcessorSize;
        bestfit(pcb,mem);
    }
```

Comment: You are missing a final `else` clause.  What happens if both `if` statements are false?

Comment: It feels like there is a for-loop missing in your code. Where does the `i` variable get defined?

Comment: We would need the definition of `PCB` in order to give you information.

Comment: Are you assigning (associating) memory with a processor or allocating blocks of memory?

Comment: Where is `start` defined?  What is its type?  **Edit** your post with the answer.

Comment: You need to discuss this assignment with your instructor.

Comment: allocating block of memory  there was a for loop i forgot to change it it ran infinite time so i removed it

Comment: i already discuss this with my instructor. he said i can use whatever i want as long as i get it to work :/ don't think that is very helpful at all

Comment: i just need a little bit of help on how to check front and back after deleting and where to store beginning and end of memory :/ i honestly thought doubly linked list would work but i can't seem to get it work that well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is a basic block allocator. You mention that your teacher doesn't care how it's implemented, as long as it works. While that may not be very helpful as far as direction, it does give us a lot of leeway in our implementation.

The best-fit strategy is simply selecting the smallest available block which satisfies the request. If the available list is sorted by block size, the best-fit block is the lower bound, making the container `std::multimap` perfectly suited for this task.

Normally it might be considered bad practice to use a container like this in a memory allocator (better to repurpose free store), but again, since Teach doesn't care, we might as well make things easy.

Here each block reserves space for a header. This only stores block size, but additional fields can be added. Initially the available list contains one large block. If the block found is larger than the request by some threshold, the block is split in two and the remainder is placed back on the available list.

```
// memory block header size in words.
#define HEADER_SIZE static_cast<word_type>(1)

// extract block size from block header.
#define BLOCK_SIZE(location) \
    (heap[(location) - HEADER_SIZE])

// heap types/members.
typedef unsigned int word_type;
constexpr  word_type heap_size = 1000000;
word_type  heap[heap_size];

// key: block size; data: block location.
std::multimap<word_type, word_type> free_list;

void heap_initialize()
{
    word_type next = HEADER_SIZE;
    BLOCK_SIZE(next) = heap_size;
    release(next);
}

void release(word_type p)
{
    if (p != 0)
        free_list.insert(std::make_pair(BLOCK_SIZE(p), p));
}

word_type acquire(word_type request)
{
    if (request == 0)
        return 0;

    // threshold minimum is (header + 1*data word).
    word_type threshold = 8;
    request = (request + HEADER_SIZE + (threshold-1))
            / threshold * threshold;

    // locate best-fit.
    auto best_iter = free_list.lower_bound(request);

    // no suitable block found.
    if (best_iter == free_list.end())
        throw std::bad_alloc();

    // extract index; update free list.
    word_type best = best_iter->second;
    free_list.erase(best_iter);

    // split block.
    if (BLOCK_SIZE(best) > request + threshold) {
        word_type  next  = best + request;
        BLOCK_SIZE(next) = BLOCK_SIZE(best) - request;
        BLOCK_SIZE(best) = request;
        release(next);
    }
    return best;
}
```

The test for this code with output can be viewed [here](http://ideone.com/ePsMsw). An alternate implementation using a doubly linked list and block coalesce is [here](http://ideone.com/Cpuy2k).

Hope this helps. Good luck.